# Is there a way to make a colorbox object draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Is there a jQuery script that will make colorbox windows draggable?

I found a one called [easydrag](http://www3.unca.edu/cm/map/mapCB/easy.js) that *works* but it gets *sticky* once the colorbox is dragged to the outer boundaries of the page. See my *easydrag* [sample page](http://www3.unca.edu/cm/easy.html).

I am looking to get the *easydrag* script working properly OR find an alternative script that works well with colorbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) for that - if *draggable* is the only function you seak, UI may be overkill, but it works:

`$('#colorbox').draggable();`